# Should I include data nodes in discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've just created three dedicated master nodes and one data node for my cluster.

Now, I need to configure an initial list of nodes that will be contacted to discover and form a cluster.

I included IP addresses of the three dedicated master nodes as the values of `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts`, but should I also include the IP address of the data node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding IP address of 3 master nodes is sufficient. Data node's IP Address is not necessary.